# How to use render-header function in table-column in Element library?

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I need to have a custom table header (title + svg + tooltip) for Element table.
I am trying to use the 'render-header' function without luck.
To be more specific - how to print the label + SVG (with tooltip on hover) for each column?

Html:

```
 <el-table-column property="name" label="Indicator" :render-header="appendTip">
        </el-table-column>
```

Script:

```
appendTip(h, { column }) {
      return h(
        "el-tooltip",
        {
          attrs: {
            effect: "dark",
            content: "Test",
            placement: "top"
          }
        },
        [h("el-button", ["Tooltip"])]
      );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

```
appendTip(h, { column, $index }) {
      // Function(h, { column, $index })
      return h("span", [
        column.label,
        h(
          "el-popover",
          {
            props: {
              placement: "top",
              // title: "hello",
              // width: "200",
              trigger: "hover",
              content: this.test(column.label)
            }
          },
          [
            h(
              "i",
              {
                slot: "reference",
                class: "el-icon-info"
                //style: "color:gray;font-size:16px;margin-left:10px;"
              },
              ""
            )
          ]
        )
      ]);
```

I used this as a reference:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Answer (score 0):

I have modified little bit for my requirements, 
I do not need [i] button for popover, I needed popover on header text, so the syntax that worked for me is given below

```
appendTip: function (h, { column, $index }) {

var content = "Popover content"
if (column.property == "isrequired") {
    content = "Value is Required";
}
else {
    return column.label;
}

return h(
        "el-popover",
        {
            props: {
                placement: "top",
                // title: "hello",
                // width: "200",
                trigger: "hover",
            }
        },
        [
            content,
            h(
                "span",
                {
                    slot: "reference",
                },
                column.label
            )
        ]
    );
},
```

Thanks badigard for your answer, that helped me a lot.